# Is Liferay suitable for an API Documentation Site?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I've been tasked with creating a documentation website for some services that we expose externally.  Part of my task is to find out what the best base software would be to build this site.  One of my specific objectives is to determine whether or not the Liferay Portal software or its plugins are suitable for building what is primarily functioning as an API documentation website.  It seems like Liferay is meant for more content-driving applications, such as news, wikis, blogs, etc.

If Liferay is suitable for this task, are there any pointers on what the general layout should be for the site?

Liferay itself is proving to be rather complicated to learn, so I figured that it'd be better to figure out if I'm wasting my time or not before really diving into learning how to use it.

At the same time, are there any better, non-commercial alternatives?

Thanks!

Comment: Liferay is a complete package and can be an over-kill for a small use-case like having just an API Documentation. Though if you can elaborate more on what exactly you would require as an API documentation like will it require collaboration, many permission levels, authentication etc or simply a site with some content and hyperlinks like in Wikis, then we can say if Liferay would be a good choice or not.

Comment: I don't think collaboration is really required.  However, there are two or three different permission levels (guest, site member, and admin, basically).  Authentication is also required through LDAP.  I think my biggest problem is finding portlets that serve content the way I have envisioned.  I don't want to start working on a portlet only to find that I've wasted my time.

Comment: For general API documentation I think liferay offers Wikis and Web-content. You can have a look at [Structures and Templates](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen03-advanced-content-creation-0) for some advanced web-content stuff and to see if that can fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I am creating web portal using Liferay and I implemented a simple document browsing page. I was using amazon java libraries to accomplish that and it was quite easy(just download all of the jars, include them in your portlet library folder and AWS(AmazonS3) is ready to use). On the other, the programmatic part of creating this portals with Liferay is quite a lot. I suggest you  if you don't like programming to chose another software :)

I hope this was helpful! Its just an advice not a concrete answer.

Good luck with developing your website :)